# Scrolling down in windows phone 7 design pane in visual studio

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit

Silly question, but how do you scroll down in the wp7 design pane for visual studio ?

I have a lot of `StackPanel` elements in the page and the design pane only shows the first ones who fit the wp screen. i can't find a way to scroll down to the other elemets.

in the capture attached, you can see that after "Units in stock" it doesn't show anything else although i have more elements after.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, actually that is a good question. When I had this issue I was simply dragging the whole container up and altering the content and then putting it back. I can't remember an option for scrolling :/

Comment: Have you tried opening your project in blend?

Comment: +1 for use of Blend for this kind of thing.

Comment: first time i hear about blend. looks much more powerful then the built in designer. i will check it out.

Comment: Michael, better get habituated with Blend for Windows Phone development. Its more design and less coding, isnt it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried increasing the design height in the statement which somewhat looks like this? You may find it on the top of your XAML page.

`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="1500" />`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding the question, just put your StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer.  That's what I've done in my apps.

Comment: I am talking about scrolling down when the emulator is not running, while inside visual studio and not when the emulator is running

Comment: Ah - gotcha.  I don't know the answer to that.